# How to upload a file in NodeJS without Express

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to pick up a file from a form and save it to myself on disk in any folder. I would like to do it by sockets, but I do not know how to handle it. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

main.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var path = require('path');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write("Not Found");
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.write(data, 'utf8');
            res.end();
        }
    });
}).listen(8000);

var listener = io.listen(server);

listener.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("Connected");
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("Disconnect");
    });

    socket.on('form.message', function (data) {
        // here to handle the file ??
        socket.emit('new.message', {msg: data});
    });
});
```

index.html(client)

```
<script>

        $(function () {
            var socket = io.connect();

            var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
            var $file = $('#file');
            var $outputFile = $('#outputFile');
            var obj = {
                file: $file.val(),
            };
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(obj);
            socket.emit('form.message', obj);
            $file.val('');
            socket.on('new.message', function (data) {
                $outputFile.append('<div class="well">' + data.msg.file + '</div>');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploader-in-nodejs--net-25445

Comment: Not exactly what it was, I just want to save the file from the form to disk, nothing else

Comment: Why do you want to make it with sockets? Maybe that's not the best solution.

Comment: So, how would it look without sockets?

Comment: @NikolaLukic, I did it thanks to your link. Files are saved in disk, but if I write e.g PDF, video or exe file, I can't open this. But txt and image file opened ok. What may be the problem?